# Trying to run mongo3 gem on Ubuntu 10.10. Help!

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I'm trying to run the ruby gem "mongo3" (http://mongo3.com/)

I'm new to gem, but I would *think* that running "gem mongo3" should execute it, but I get this error:

```
chris@Zombie:~$ gem mongo3
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command mongo3
```

So I did "gem which mongo3" and it said it is located at "/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo3-0.1.3/lib/mongo3.rb". I then ran "ruby /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo3-0.1.3/lib/mongo3.rb" with the following result:

```
chris@Zombie:~$ ruby /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo3-0.1.3/lib/mongo3.rb
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo3-0.1.3/lib/mongo3/node.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo3-0.1.3/lib/mongo3/node.rb:1
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo3-0.1.3/lib/mongo3.rb:41:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo3-0.1.3/lib/mongo3.rb:41:in `require_all_libs_relative_to'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo3-0.1.3/lib/mongo3.rb:41:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo3-0.1.3/lib/mongo3.rb:41:in `require_all_libs_relative_to'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo3-0.1.3/lib/mongo3.rb:53
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - I suspect that ruby and gems are confused about where the gems should be loaded from or something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do a `gem mongo3` or `ruby /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo3-0.1.3/lib/mongo3.rb`. Instead, just simply run `mongo3`.

Make sure to follow the usage instructions [here](https://github.com/derailed/mongo3) to configure it or you'll get runtime errors.

**Edit:** If you don't install the gem using `sudo`, then you won't have proper write access to `/usr/bin`, meaning the `mongo3` executable will not be in your path. You'll probably see a warning like this when installing:

```
WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /var/lib/gems/1.8 and 
          /usr/bin aren't both writable.
WARNING:  You don't have /home/chris/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH, 
          gem executables will not run.
```

You have two options: install the gem using `sudo gem install mongo3` so it properly links to `/usr/bin`, or add `/home/chris/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin` to your path.

Comment: When I enter "mongo3" I get "mongo3: command not found". Those are the usage instructions that I've been using. Still not sure what's wrong.

Comment: What if you run `/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mongo3-0.1.3/bin/mongo3`?

Comment: Assuming that running the command I just recommended works, then I think my edited answer should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Good and bad news: the command you suggested does work. I uninstalled and re-installed as sudo with no success with the /usr/bin problem, but I was able to run it from its directory.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Good and bad news: the command you suggested does work. I uninstalled and re-installed as sudo with no success with the /usr/bin problem, but I was able to run it from its directory. On the negative side, I also get "Internal server error" when I load up the page in the browser that it is supposed to produce, but that is a different problem.

Comment: It should spit out a backtrace into your terminal that you can step through to see where the problem is (it did the same thing to me) when I clicked on a node.